# How to automatically add lookup field based on request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have UserViewSet with based on viewsets.ModelViewSet.

It is attached to url `/users/`.

I want to create `/user/` url with **GET** and **PATCH** methods.

How to link `/user/` to UserViewSet, so when doing **GET** or **PATCH** methods it automatically linked to `/users/request.user.id/`
**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet)):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    ...
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='users')
???
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use require_GET or require_http_method

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/$', UserViewSet.as_view()),
    url(r'^user/(?P<id>\d+)/$', require_GET(UserViewSet.as_view())),
]
```

for more methods, a require_http_method decorator which receives allowed methods in its parameters, e.g.:

```
  url(r'^user/(?P<model_id>\d+)/$', require_http_method(['GET', 'DELETE'])(UserViewSet.as_view()))
```

Comment: I mean just using urls like url(r'^user/$', require_GET(UserViewSet.as_view()))

Comment: use generic view instead then, there is generics.ListCreateAPIView, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIVIew

Comment: ViewSets are used for doing list and single object methods with same url